# Strange data in HTTP request

Tags: networking, web-server, tcp

I have a HTTP server that serve many short time connections from many clients, the server logged that there are some invalid HTTP requests, so I decide to capture the network traffic. This is what I got:

![image][1]

Because of HTTP keep-alive, the stream looks like have 3 requests, the first(end at `APN: m-wap.0001`) is OK, but the second and third are not. I don't think user send such that request, I think it is a network problem (all of invalid requests look come from 3G network user, behind NAT network). We use `tcp_tw_reuse` and `tcp_tw_recycle` in earlier time, but I turn them off for now to avoid problem may relate to NAT network. But there are still some invalid requests, Do you have a suggest?

**Update**: Finally I found the answer, the network provider was alter the request by adding 4 last header, and they need to update SEQ/ACK number, but it seem that they did not do it correct in case of re-transmission.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I provided the answer in the update of question.

Answer (score 0):

Are you missing part of this TCP conversation in your packet capture?

The client is sending Acknowledgements and the `ACK` value is increasing, meaning data has been received from the other end, but there is no such data in your capture.

If the remote end sent a `FIN` but still had some data in its send buffer, or data which had been sent then delayed and arrived out-of-order, those might explain why the client resets in the last frame.

Comment: We use LVS and in/out stream on different network interface, so this capture only contain incoming-stream.